# A question on calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, area

The question is:

> In the accompanying figure the curve represented by $\rm C$ is given by $y= \rm f (x)$ where $\rm f$ is one-to-one and continuous. ${\rm C1}$ and ${\rm C2}$ are respectively $y=2x^2$ and $y=x^2$. At each point $P$ on $\rm {C1}$, assume that the areas $OAP$ and $OPB$ are equal. Here $PA, PB$ are the horizontal and vertical segments. Determine the function $f$.

[image]

My progress:
I took any arbitrary point $x > 0$ and calculated the areas and found out that $$\int_{0}^{x}{\rm f}(t)dt=x{\rm f}(x)-(\frac{{\rm f}(x)}{2})^{\frac {3}{2}}.$$Now the problem is that we do not know that $f$ is differentiable or not. If it was, then we could differentiate both sides of the equation(since $f$ continuous is given) w.r.t $x$ to obtain $$f^{'}(x)(x-\frac {3}{4\sqrt {2}}\sqrt {f(x)})=0.$$ Now since $f$ is one-to-one and continuous, we can easily show that $f$ is monotonic and hence $f$ cannot attain a relative extremum anywhere and hence $f^{'}(x)=0$ for no $x$, i.e. for all $x$, $$\sqrt {f(x)}=\frac {4\sqrt {2}x}{3}$$ wherefrom we conclude $f(x)=\frac{32x^{2}}{9}.$ 
 How do we prove that $f$ is differentiable?
 Also I think we can solve the problem another way round, i.e we first show that $\frac {32x^2}{9}$ indeed is a solution and then that there can be at most one solution of $f$. Can we do it this way, i.e show the uniqueness? Thank you for your help in advance.

(P.S.  It would also be helpful if someone tells me how to draw good diagrams here. I have drawn this in paint and the graphs look horrible.)

Comment: Do you mean the areas between the respective curves bounded by the points $OAB$ and $OPB$ are equal? Or do you mean the triangles $\Delta OAP$ and $\Delta OBP$ have equal area?

Comment: No, no, no...not triangles, between the curves, @JohnD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the segments $PA$ and $PB$ until they meet the axes at $A'$ and $B\,'$, respectively.

[image: graph of three functions]

Since arc $OP$ is a graph of $y = 2x^2$ and arc $OB$ is a graph of $y = x^2$, we know that the area enclosed by the figure $OBB\,'$ is half the area enclosed by $OPB\,'$; and the area enclosed by $OPB$ is the difference of those two areas, so it also is half the area of $OPB\,'$.

But we also know that the area of $OPB\,'$, that is, under the parabolic arc $OP$, is one third the area of the rectangle $OB\,'PA'$, and the area of $OPA'$ (between the arc $OP$ and the $y$-axis) is two-thirds of the area of the rectangle.  The area of $OPA$, which is equal to the area of $OPB$, is therefore one quarter of the area of $OPA'$, and $OAA'$ has three-fourths of the area of $OPA'$.

Now, since $f$ is one-to-one, $f^{-1}$ exists on the range of $f$, 
and the arcs $OP$ and $OA$ can be described by the equations 
$x = \sqrt{y/2}$ and $x = f^{-1}(y)$, respectively.  From the preceding facts, 
the areas between those arcs and the $y$-axis satisfy the equation

$$ \frac{3}{4} \int_0^Y \sqrt{\frac{y}{2}} dy = \int_0^Y f^{-1}(y) \, dy $$

where $Y$ is the $y$-coordinate of $P$.

Taking the integral on each side of the equation above as a function of $Y$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus the derivatives of these integrals exist and are equal to  $\sqrt{Y/2}$ and $f^{-1}(Y)$, respectively.  Therefore,

$$ \frac{3}{4} \sqrt{\frac{y}{2}} = f^{-1}(y). $$

If $x = \frac{3}{4} \sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}$, then $y = \frac{32}{9} x^2$, so

$$ x = f^{-1} \left( \frac{32}{9} x^2 \right), $$

and applying $f$ to both sides, we find that

$$  f(x) = \frac{32}{9} x^2. $$

Comment: Can you give an insight as to why my method does not work?

Comment: I'm not sure your method _cannot_ work; I saw where you pointed out that one of the steps requires $f$ to be differentiable, and rather than try to prove that fact (which happens to be true in the end, of course), I stepped back to see if there was another way to do the proof from the beginning. I happily found that it takes only some very elementary knowledge of calculus.

Comment: It's unclear to me that $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ comes into this answer at all. I do explicitly use the graph of a function to divide a rectangle in two parts, but that function is $y = 2x^2$, which we know is differentiable (and in any case we can find the area of either part of the rectangle quite easily).

Comment: You're absolutely correct, with $OAA$ defined as an integral of $f^{-1}$ we don't even need to consider that.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous and monotonic, it is differentiable almost everywhere.  So except possibly on a set of measure zero you can follow your steps to

$f'(x) (x-\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{f(x)})= 0$.

Under your assumption that the derivative of $f$ does not vanish, you find an everywhere-differentiable function that satisfies the equal-area condition.  So you have, in fact, produced a solution where differentiation can be justified and the derivative does not vanish. The solution you found is unique (modulo sets of measure zero).

Your argument breaks down if you cannot assume that the derivative is non-zero.  Is this possible for a continuous, non-decreasing function?  The answer is yes -- the Cantor function or Devil's Staircase has a derivative that exists and equals zero almost everywhere.  However, you are steering clear of such a pathological case in finding the smooth solution.

Comment: Nice answer. I don't know at what level of mathematics student/reader this problem was aimed, maybe calculus students or maybe a contest type problem where the crux of the problem was precisely this level of nuance. I suspect the former, and in this case I also suspect they just didn't give quite strong enough hypotheses ($f'(x)\not=0$ $\forall x$) to get the "clean" answer. The statement could be tweaked to say $f(x),f'(x)>0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @JohnD, this problem came in the entrance examination(in 2010) of the Indian Statistical Institute. So, I cannot understand a single assertion RRL made in the answer. An elementary solution will be helpful.

Comment: @IndrayudhRoy In simple terms, I believe whoever wrote the question simply failed to state the hypotheses strong enough to resolve your issue. I think they should have said "$f$ is one-to-one and differentiable"; and then the solution they wanted was your solution. I do very much like the question. If you have other interesting ones, please point me to a link or post them here.

Comment: @JohnD, I think the problem can be solved even though $f$ differentiable is not given. This is a question of the entrance examination (B. Math 2010) of the Indian Statistical Institute. It is one of the best undergraduate colleges in India for mathematics. I do not think they will make such mistakes.

Comment: @RRL, here is the problem(no. 2).... http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=78&cid=231&year=2010&sid=ad4b158a1a8439dfa05e6fd5e61d0e59

Answer (score -1):

First, show that the function you derived (using stronger assumption) solves the problem. Then show that the problem has unique solution on the class of monotone continuous functions.

I also sketch a proof of uniqueness. Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be two different monotone continuous functions solving the integral equation. Necessarily $f_1(0)=f_2(0)=0$, hence there exist (using continuity) a points $0\leq t_0<t_1$ such that $f_1(t)=f_2(t)$ for all $t\in [0,t_0]$ and (WLOG) $f_2(t)<f_1(t)$ for $t\in(t_0,t_1]$. Now there exists $t_2>t_1$ such that $f_1(t_1)=f_2(t_2)$. When you sketch this situation, you should realize contradiction.

A regularity result for integral equatlity holds and can be obtained by the Implicit function theorem.